# Possible to filter rows in XML-Import?

Tags: xml, filter

I am importing data from a file into a software through an XML-template, the data is imported without any issues, but I would like to add a filter in the import to leave certain rows from the data out. Is this possible to achieve directly in the XML-template? I will try to give an example here below:

Let us say the table for import looks like the table attached. I would like to leave all the rows out which do not contain the word "ID" in column 3.

```
    <collection name="XXXXX" mapTo="YYYYY">
        <collection name="xxxxxx" mapTo="yyyyyy">
            <row name="Information" mapTo="Info">
                <column type="String" name="Col1" mapTo="Column1"/>
                <column type="String" name="Col2" mapTo="Column2"/>
                <column type="String" name="Col3" mapTo="Column3"/>
            </row>
        </collection>
    </collection>
```

Any ideas for this?

Thank you!

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUGLM.png)

Comment: (1) Nobody knows anything about your import process. (2) you can filter out unnecessary XML data by running XSLT transformation BEFORE running your import.

Answer (score 0):

A standard use case for XSLT. You haven't described the technology stack you are using, but inserting an XSLT transformation into the import pipeline should be perfectly straightforward. If you're able to use XSLT 3.0 it would look like this:

```
<xsl:transform
   version="3.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="row[column[@name='Col3][contains(., 'ID')]]"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

It's basically a transformation with two rules: the `xsl:mode` says that the default action is to copy everything unchanged, and the `xsl:template` says that if an element matches certain conditions, the required action is to do nothing (i.e. exclude the element from the output).